# How to implement multiple datasource configurations in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

We are moving our application to Spring Boot and one of the problems we would like to solve is managing multiple `EntityManager`/DAOs. I've read about multi-tenancy implementations in Spring but they all seem to rely on having at least one connection at startup.

Our application starts with no connection/`EntityManager` instantiated, and only when a request is sent through the endpoint `/start` with the database parameters we instantiate it. We can also have multiple database connections that are stored in a map with an ID as key.

Is it possible to implement something like this in Spring? Is it possible to have Spring manage all the persistence parameters that are created dynamically?

Comment: Yes, but not easily.  Your best option would be to start the app with all your datasources preconfigured, and configure a AbstractRoutingDatasource dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately we get all the database connection details in the body of the `/start` endpoint and we are not authorized to change this behavior. I guess we'll continue without Spring managing our entites...